# Logic error with list indicies when finding optimized binary search tree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, optimization, binary-search-tree

I adapted pseudocode for an optimized binary search tree algorithm from [Cormen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) to run some sample data, but there is a logic error somewhere that is preventing correct output in the root list.

I've checked the code against Cormen several times, and it appears that the problem is in my list indices (subscripts).

But because in this case Cormen uses both zero-based and one-based arrays in the diagrams, I have absolutely no idea how to modify my list indices to correct the problem. It appears the author broke the one-based convention typical of the text for this particular algorithm.

Can anyone with experience in OBST see the adjustment necessary to correct the following Python?

```
def obst(p,q):
    """Adapted from Cormen, pg. 402"""
    n  = len(q)
    rn = range(n)
    e  = [[99999]*n for _ in rn]
    w  = [[0]*n for _ in rn]
    root = [[0]*n for _ in rn]

    for i in range(1, n):
        e[i][i - 1] = w[i][i - 1] = q[i - 1]


    for l in range(1,n):
        for i in range(1, n-l):
            j = i+l-1
            w[i][j] = w[i][j-1] + p[j] + q[j]
            for r in range(i,j+1):
                t = e[i][r-1] + e[r+1][j] + w[i][j]
                if t < e[i][j]:
                    e[i][j] = t
                    root[i][j] = r
    return (e,root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = [0, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
    q = [0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1]
    assert len(p) == len(q)
    d = obst(p,q,len(p))
    print(d[1])
```

EDIT: I changed some indices. According to Cormen, the expected output for the root table alone (which is in the second element of the returned tuple) is as follows:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4],
    [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

My output when n is `len(p)`:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Your assignment `e[i][j] = float('inf')` needs to be moved out of the loop.

Comment: Your inf shouldn't be moved completely outside, just outside the inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Given you can just map 1..n+1 back down to 0..n, then it makes things slightly simpler to handle:

```
def obst(p, q):
    pn = len(p)
    qn = len(q)
    e = [[0]*qn for _ in range(qn)]
    w = [[0]*qn for _ in range(qn)]
    root = [[0]*pn for _ in range(pn)]

    for i in range(qn):
        e[i][i] = q[i]
        w[i][i] = q[i]

    for l in range(1, qn):
        for i in range(0, qn-l):
            j = i + l
            e[i][j] = float('inf')
            w[i][j] = w[i][j-1] + p[j-1] + q[j]
            for r in range(i, j):
                t = e[i][r] + e[r+1][j] + w[i][j]
                if t < e[i][j]:
                    e[i][j] = t
                    root[i][j-1] = r+1
    return (e, root)
```

This only operates on a triangle of the matrix.
Output:

```
>>> p = [0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
>>> q = [0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1]
>>> d = obst(p, q)
>>> d[1]
[[1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 4],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 5],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 5]]
>>> d[0]
[[0.05, 0.45000000000000007, 0.9, 1.25, 1.75, 2.75],
 [0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1.2, 2.0],
 [0, 0, 0.05, 0.25, 0.6, 1.2999999999999998],
 [0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.30000000000000004, 0.9],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.5],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1]]
```

Note: I removed the padding 0.0 in p
Note: I added 1 to r to output the exact same as the example
Note: I checked the values for `e` and `w` and these are also correct

Comment: This does not match expected output. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: Because I have mapped down to 0..n you will not get the empty top row and r will be 1 less than your output... adding 1 to r and ignoring the top row is close to your expected output and should give you something to work from.

Comment: My understanding is that the top row helps one find dummy keys, particularly on the left side of the tree.

Comment: I don't think it does, I've updated the code and fixed the indices and generate the right values for root